# Avoiding use of a temp table by using sub queries

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I want to create a subquery to avoid the use of a temp table. Right now I have:

```
select id,COUNT (id)as Attempts
into #tmp
from Table1
where State in ('SD')
and Date >=  cast( GETDATE() -7 as date )
group by Accountid having COUNT (accountid) > 2

select *
from #tmp a join Table1 b on a.id= b.id
and b.Date >=  cast( GETDATE() -7 as date )
where CAST(Date as date) = cast(GETDATE()-1 as date)
order by a.id,b.Date
```

Is there a way to get this result in just one query?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.  There might be a simpler approach.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for doing so? Very often *adding* the use of a  temp table (aka divide and conquer) is the more performant option for a multitude of reasons.

Comment: The reason I wanted to skip the usage of a temp table is because that doesn't work in Power BI. Only way I could get it to work is using a subquery as shown below.

Comment: Ok that's a justifiable reason :-)

Comment: Note that `CAST(Date as date) = cast(GETDATE()-1 as date)` is not properly sargeable. `Date >= CAST(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AS date) AND Date < CAST(GETDATE() AS date)` is likely more efficient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `#tmp` in the second query with the first query enclosed in parenthesis, as in:

```
select *
from (
  select id,COUNT (id) as Attempts
  from Table1
  where State in ('SD')
  and Date >=  cast( GETDATE() -7 as date )
  group by Accountid having COUNT (accountid) > 2
) a join Table1 b on a.id= b.id
and b.Date >=  cast( GETDATE() -7 as date )
where CAST(Date as date) = cast(GETDATE()-1 as date)
order by a.id,b.Date
```

The first query becomes a "table expression".